# Domain computers not able to access public website

Tags: website, active-directory

I've made a bit of a mistake. I've created an Active Directory domain with the same name as our company website, so whenever domain users try to load our website, they are redirected to our domain controller instead.

I've tried looking at the DNS records, but I can't find the error.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your internal Active Directory DNS server has the same zone as your public zone, *and believes it's authoritative for that zone.* Therefore, when internal clients ask for the record `www.example.com` it looks at its own records, finds none, and tells the client no such website exists.

In your case you have a couple of options:

1. Copy all of the DNS records necessary to access your website from your public DNS zone to your internal zone. In the future, you'll need to be sure any relevant changes in your public zone are duplicated in your internal one.
2. Re-create your Active Directory domain. Best practice (see [here](http://www.mdmarra.com/2012/11/why-you-shouldnt-use-local-in-your.html) and [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727085.aspx)) is to use a subdomain of your external domain, such as `ad.example.com`.